# Execute code (fill listbox) when opening a document or updating?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm having such a hard time learning VBA. No clear guide from basics to more advanced stuff. I know coding but understanding the Object model and event system in VBA is somewhat messy for me.

I just want to do simple things that is taking me too long, like filling a Listbox (the one you embed in the worksheet, not the userform one) in Office 2002. I want the Listbox to be filled by default everytime, when the document is opened, the source of the list changes etc.

I tried writing the code inside the Worksheet inside a procedure, outside a procedure and nothing works.
I for example hover the mouse over the listbox and the code executes with compilation error, when I did'nt write code for mouseover event.

Inside a Worksheet directly I wrote

```
ListBox1.AddItem "test"
ListBox1.AddItem "test 2"
```

etc...

I excepted that it would work but does not and can't see where I can find all the events inside Excel for Worksheets. The dropdown menus inside the VBA Editor are set to "General" and "Declarations" and there is no more options in the second one.

Comment: The best way to learn VBA is to record a macro while doing <your thing> manually. This will result in bad code, but you will at least see the relevant parts of the object model.

Comment: @Sam The thing is that I am not able to fill a sheet form listbox using a GUI apparently. I need to use VBA and I'm not sure where I have to place that code.

Comment: Those listboxes comes in three variants: Data Validation, ActiveX or Form Controls. Which one are we talking about?

Comment: @Sam Not sure. I have the spanish version, so the translation for each controls are: the ones I'm using say "form boxes" and the other ones say "form". Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stumbled upon one of the parts of Excel where the object model doesn't cover normal use.
The data source for those list boxes is a range that are set at
*Right Click on the control* - *Format Control...* - *Control* - *Input range*
Here you can set it manually to a range, like $A$1:$A$3, but that will give some problems controlling, so do like this instead:

1. Create a list of options on a sheet in the workbook
2. Select that range and give it a name
3. Set that name as input range for the list box
4. When you need to add values to the listbox, just redefine the named range.

The code for step 4 would look something like this:

```
Dim RowCount As Integer
With ActiveWorkbook.Names("OptionList")
    RowCount = .RefersToRange.Rows.Count + 1
    .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(RowCount)
    .RefersToRange(RowCount) = "New value"
End With
```

Comment: Just a question. When you start with a dot "." is it like using the keyword "this"?

Comment: No, that is used together with `With` - `End With`. The object defined at the `With` line is the invisible part to the left of the dot.